# Android to display a text on Text View from String-array items and changing it on left and right swipe

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview, swipe

I am just days old to android.In my application I have a List View displaying planets name, and when user clicks on the list view item i.e any of the planet name, another activity will gets opened in respect of which planet is clicked on list view, like suppose if user choose "earth", an activity gets opened having Text View display and on that text view, I am displaying some facts(say 10 facts) about planet Earth that I have stored in string-array items(displaying only 1 fact at a time). Now, when user swipes left or right,the text gets changed depending on whether it is swiped left or right.

```
Tasks that I've managed to perform
```

- I am able to set the list view items i.e lists of planet and I've implemented the onItemSelectListener() to it.
- I've created the 9 activities also for each planet and I am able to call the particular activity for which the item is clicked using Intent().
- I have declared the facts for each planet in string-array items.But don't know how to set them on Text View.

`Tasks that I'm trying to achieve`

- Like when click on Earth, I am starting another activity that is displaying the first fact from the string-array items. I want when user swipes left or right, the second fact will gets displayed.

P.S.. Though I am able to change the facts from string-array items, but for that I was using next and previous buttons in which I using a counter, but I want to use the swipe.

I tried several tuts about swipes but did understand much. Please help and suggest.

- One more thing, I am having a Samsung Galaxy Y S5360, how to install plug-ins in it, so that I can test my application directly because my emulator sucks.(i've heard using Kies slows down the system-any other alternative you can offer)

Thanks a lot

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        ListView lv;

        String[] list = new String[] { "Mercury","Venus","Earth","Mars","Jupiter",
                "Saturn","Uranus","Neptune","Pluto" };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adps = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    list);
            lv.setAdapter(adps);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                        long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                Mercury.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
    // similarly for all other 8 cases

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

            // final String[] quo = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quotes);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Mercury.java

```
public class motivatinal extends Activity {

    int counter = 0;
    TextView mercury;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.motivational);

        String[] mer = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.motivational);
        mercury.setText(mer);
    // do not know how to display string array items on text view.
   // mercury.settext is showing error.
}
}
```

Comment: You are looking for Viewpager.... Viewpager allows change the data on swipe event

Comment: Check out this question/answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894580/android-change-textview-within-a-viewpager