# How can I prevent my findViewById method from being called too early?

Tags: java, android

So I've got a `Dialog`, which contains some `editText` fields (these are spread over 3 fragments, shown by a viewpager, in case this info matters). For an `edit` action, I want to create that dialog with some values already put in.

At the moment I'm trying to do it like this:

```
editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GeneralSettingsInitialInputDialog GSIID = new GeneralSettingsInitialInputDialog();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("name", TitleTV.getText().toString());
                args.putString("ip", IPaddressET.getText().toString());
                args.putString("port", PortET.getText().toString());
                args.putString("username", UsernameET.getText().toString());
                args.putString("pass", PasswordET.getText().toString());
                Log.d(tag, args.toString());

                GSIID.setArguments(args);
                GSIID.show(((Activity) context).getFragmentManager(), "GSIID");
```

This shows the onClickListener for the edit button (which is contained in a `recyclerView`. This particular bit comes from my `Adapter`).

After that, I tried this in the `onCreateDialog` method for the GSIID dialogFragment:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    ma = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    dbHandler = DBHandler.getInstance(getActivity());

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_generalsettingsviewpager, null);

    mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    mPagerAdapter = new TestAdapter();
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);


    if (getArguments() != null) {
        ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.IDName)).setText(getArguments().getString("name"));
        ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.IDIPaddress)).setText(getArguments().getString("ip"));
        ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.IDPort)).setText(getArguments().getString("port"));
        ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.IDUsername)).setText(getArguments().getString("username"));
        ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.IDPassword)).setText(getArguments().getString("pass"));
    }


    // Build Dialog
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Setup Device")
            .setMessage("Please add all required details for your Raspberry Pi here.")
            .setPositiveButton("Next", null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    return builder.show();
}
```

This returned a `NPE`, saying I was trying to use `setText` on a null, so `view.findViewById()` is returning null. I thought I'd fix that by moving this code to the `onStart()` method, to make sure everything is there before I try to set stuff on it, but I'm still getting the same error.

All this time, I'm noticing that the dialog does NOT open before the error occurs, so I'm guessing the `findViewById()` method is still called too soon, but I don't know how to fix that.

I have tested to make sure my code is not broken, by having the above code run when a button on the GSIID dialog is pressed (so the dialog is opened then). This did indeed work.

So, basically: How can I prevent this `findViewById` method from being called too early?

Comment: You mentioned the EditTexts being "spread over 3 fragments". So they are not part of the "fragment_generalsettingsviewpager" layout file you inflated? When and how do you add the Fragments to the ViewPager?

Comment: They indeed aren't part of that layout file. The fragments are added in a PagerAdapter. I'm not 100% sure about the workings of that.

Comment: `view.findViewById()` will return null if there is no child (or grand-grandchild ) View with that Id in the inflated Viewgroup.

Comment: Yes, I know. The issue however is, how to make sure it returns the proper element.

Comment: You can access the Fragments via adapter.getItem(position), maybe you should try to write some "setter methods" for the Fragments

Comment: `getItem()` is not available for a `pagerAdapter` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my day is saved, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894580/android-change-textview-within-a-viewpager/21894872#21894872) post.

Basically, you just need a method inside your custom `PagerAdapter` that returns the view for the index you give it.

#### CustomAdapter

**New:** *Constructor* (I believe that's what it's called)

```
private View view0 = null;
private View view1 = null;
private View view2 = null;
private View viewError = null;

public TestAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
    view0 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_generalsettingsinputdialog1, null);
    view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_generalsettingsinputdialog2, null);
    view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_generalsettingsinputdialog3, null);
    viewError = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewpagererror, null);
}
```

**Changed:** *instantiateItem()*

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View instView = getViewAtPosition(position);
    instView.setTag("layoutThingy"+position);
    container.addView(instView);
    instView.requestFocus();
    return instView;
}
```

**New:** *getViewAtPosition()*

```
public View getViewAtPosition(int position) {
    View view = null;
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            view = view0;
            break;
        case 1:
            view = view1;
            break;
        case 2:
            view = view2;
            break;
        default:
            view = viewError;
    }
    return view;
}
```

---

#### Other stuff

When initialising PagerAdapter, make sure you pass a `LayoutInflater` as an argument. For me it was like this: `mPagerAdapter = new TestAdapter(getActivity().getLayoutInflater());`

Now, I did this in my `onStart()` method, but I'm guessing you can do this pretty much everywhere.

```
View page1 = mPagerAdapter.getViewAtPosition(0);
View page2 = mPagerAdapter.getViewAtPosition(1);
View page3 = mPagerAdapter.getViewAtPosition(2);

if (getArguments() != null) {
    ((EditText) page1.findViewById(R.id.IDName)).setText(getArguments().getString("name"));
    ((EditText) page2.findViewById(R.id.IDIPaddress)).setText(getArguments().getString("ip"));
    ((EditText) page2.findViewById(R.id.IDPort)).setText(getArguments().getString("port"));
    ((EditText) page3.findViewById(R.id.IDUsername)).setText(getArguments().getString("username"));
    ((EditText) page3.findViewById(R.id.IDPassword)).setText(getArguments().getString("pass"));
}
```

This properly finds all my `EditText`'s, and should properly find everything I put in my `ViewPager`. Great! Thanks all for trying to help me, and of course a big thank you to [cYrixmorten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1501613/cyrixmorten), with his great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894580/android-change-textview-within-a-viewpager/21894872#21894872).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely by looking up views in [onCreateView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) by calling the lookups on the view you're returning from this method.

Comment: I edited the code snippet from `onCreateDialog()`, so you can see this is pretty much exactly what I'm doing. As far as I"m aware, there's no difference between `onCreateDialog()` and `onCreateView()` that would have an effect on this.

Comment: Your `View` isn't null, but the lookup isn't finding something with id `IDName`, are you sure it exists?

Comment: I'm aware of this, and yes, I'm sure it exists. I'm also pretty sure the reason that it's not being found, is because the dialog isn't created yet. I just don't understand why this is so. As you can see, I call `GSIID.show()`, which pops up the dialog normally, but as soon as I try to look up `R.id.IDName` or any of the other id's, I get this NPE. To repeat on myself, I noticed that the dialog does NOT open at all when I get this error. Maybe the `viewPager` inside the `dialogFragment` has something to do with it (don't think so, but you never know)?

Comment: It has nothing to do with creating the dialog. You're inflating a view, you can lookup on that view. Doesn't matter if you create a dialog or not. That is assuming the NPE is because the `EditText`s are null.

Comment: Following up on that, it doesn't even matter where you're calling `findViewById()` as long as it's after `inflater.inflate(...)`

Comment: So that would mean that the `R.id.IDName` isn't a child of the view I'm inflating, right?

Comment: Not only is `R.id.IDName` not a child, it's also not some indirect child. Eg, it is also not a grandchild, great-grandchild and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109087/discussion-between-timmiej93-and-charles-durham).

Answer (score 0):

You need to master the life-cycle of an Activity in android this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) can help you to understand the sequence of function calls in each step of the life-cycle.

In most cases you have your views in `onCreatView()` so it is reasonable to put your `findViewById` there but in other cases you should make sure the view has been inflated before you call `findViewById`

Comment: I'm pretty aware about life-cyclse, at least for fragments. That's exactly the reason why I tried moving the lookups to `onStart()` when I noticed looking them up in `onCreateDialog()` was too early.